# Qmenu addMenu returns derived class object

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a class which is derived from QMenu but ia m not able to return the derive class object

```
myMenu * editMenu = new myMenu(); // myMenu is derived from QMenu
myMenu *preferenceMenu = new myMenu();
preferenceMenu  = editMenu->addMenu(tr("&Preferences")); // this shows error

QMenu *preferenceMenu = new QMenu();
preferenceMenu  = editMenu->addMenu(tr("&Preferences")); // this works fine
```

Answer (score 1):

[`QMenu::addMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addMenu-1) returns a pointer to a `QMenu`...

```
QMenu *QMenu::addMenu(const QString &title);
```

So the implicit downcast to `myMenu *` will fail in the following...

```
myMenu *preferenceMenu = editMenu->addMenu(tr("&Preferences"));
```

If you want to add a submenu of your own custom type then use the [`QMenu::addMenu` overload](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addMenu) that provides that functionality...

```
auto *preferences_menu = new myMenu(tr("&Preferences");
editMenu->addMenu(preferences_menu);
```

Comment: How can I downcast and set the QString to QMenu

Comment: If you want the 'Preferences' menu to be a `myMenu` rather than simply `QMenu` then you need to use the method I've shown.  Why won't that work for you?  The method you were trying to use will always create a plain `QMenu` that can *never* be downcast to anything else.